# Android Studio 3.0.1 Ignoring APP_ABI in Application.mk?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android.mk

Is Android Studio supposed to ignore values in `Application.mk` when building NDK applications?

I have changed my `Application.mk` as follows yet my project keeps building `x86`, `mips` etc. It should only be building `armeabi-v7a`

```
#APP_ABI := all
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Build output - see the x86
[image]

I have noticed references to `NDK_APP_ABI` and `NDK_DEFAULT_ABIS` inside the `setup-app.mk` file. Are these supposed to override what is contained in `Application.mk`?

Are there variables that can be specified inside the `build.gradle` files that will propagate into the `setup-app.mk` file?

Where is the best place to find documentation on this? - Google documentation is very sparse at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the technical reason is that gradle specifies APP_ABI on the command line of ndk-build that it generates. And for gnu make, command line parameters override whatever is written in the Makefile.

Make has the `override` keyword which could help... Only that this will destroy the delicate structure of externalNativeBuild. If you want your ndkBuild to cooperate with Android Studio, keep your scripts as simple and clean as possible.

The gradle plugin uses `abiFilters` to tune the build. Actually, the official docs [describe](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds.html#specify-abi) it pretty well.